# In Lucene using FieldInvertState to identify how many times field has been added to document

Tags: java, lucene

From the FieldInvertState class passed to computeNorm() in Similarity class is there any way to find out how many times a particular field was added to a document to aid me in my normalization calculation.

i.e can it differentiate between

```
doc.add(new Field(fielda,"val1");
doc.add(new Field(fielda,"val2");
```

and

```
doc.add(new Field(fielda,"val1 val2"); //added once but analyzer breaks into two terms
```

ideally return a value 2 in one case and 1 in the second

Answer (score 1):

Also see the documentation in Similarity.

Since you yourself know how many 'things' you are adding to this field, you could put this count into a DocValues field and pull it in your Similarity: you don't need the indexers help.

Comment: Hmm, Im sorry but I cannot see how to 'pull it into your Similarity', an example would help. Although Ive just realized I already have an index field that contains the required value so can I access this from my similarity ?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could use a custom attribute to specify that "val2" was added in a different way.